# Сохранить в XML файл содержимое SQL запроса

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста. В SQL запросе запрашивается содержимое столбца с названиями(А) и столбца с названиями (Б). Нужно сохранить их в XML файл.
Вот в таком формате

```html
<DataStats>
  <Colums>
    <User>
      <colum1>Столбик 1</colum1>
      <colum2>Столбик 2</colum2>
    </User>
    <User>
      <colum1>Столбик 1</colum1>
      <colum2>Столбик 2</colum2>
    </User>
  </Colums>
</DataStats>
```

Я так понимаю, что их надо  через класс сохранять.

Вот класс

```
[Serializable]
    public class DataStat
    {
        public DataStat() { }
        public List<DataStats> list = new List<DataStats>();
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class DataStats
    {
        public string MagAdr { get; set; }
        public string MagIP { get; set; }

        public DataStats() { }
        public DataStats(string MagAdr, string IPserv)
        {
            this.MagAdr = MagAdr;
            this.MagIP = IPserv;
        }
    }
```

Вот часть кода, с подключением к серверу, где после этого, должно идти сохранение,но что дальше делать, я не знаю( Совершенно не понимаю в этом. Подскажите, а лучше покажите, пожалуйста.

```
string connectionString = "server=Name; Database=test; Uid=login; Pwd=password;";
        string sqlExpression =
            "select Столбик(А), Столбик(Б)" +
            " FROM Таблица.Откуда ";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

Вот так же сериализация

```
       private void SerializeXML(DataStat data)
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataStat));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@".\Resources\Server.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            xml.Serialize(fs, data);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Читайте любую статью по чтению данных из sql сервера, там есть примеры

Comment: Находил только вывод на консоль, но никак не сохранение в xml. Вывести в консоль или лейбл и я могу. А вот что сложней, уже нет.

Comment: Разбейте свою задачу на подзадачи. Вам сначала надо в память считать данные, ну вот считайте и выведете на консоль. Как сможете это, приступайте ко второй задаче - по уже имеющимся данным в памяти, записать их в виде xml. Вторая задача вообще не связана с sql сервером.

Comment: Считывается все как одна строка, через Join. Я видимо это не правильно делаю. Я смог это записать только в формате <colum1> Все Столбцы 1</colum1> и тоже самое со вторым

Comment: Так вы и не показали, как вы считываете. У вас вон и метод для сериализация есть, но вы и результатов сериализации не показали. Вы просто какие то куски  кода скинули и непонятно, где у вас проблема.

Comment: Все верно расписано. Считывание не показываю, потому что его и нет. Я написал четко, что нужно.

Comment: А что не просто `SELECT .. FOR XML`? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Akina безумно интересно. Но наверное задам тупой вопрос. Получилось сформировать xml файл. Но. Я сформировал его через запрос в SQL менеджере. Я же могу тоже самое, сделать в коде?

Comment: Серверу совершенно параллельно, кто ему прислал запрос и куда отправить ответ.

Comment: @Akina А не подскажете тогда, что делать, после формирования запроса? Как сохранить файл?

Comment: Непонятно. Где выполняется запрос, какими средствами? Куда в файл, на сервере или на клиенте?

Comment: ох...Если бы я еще разбирался. Есть кнопка на форме. Она подключается к серверу, формирует запрос и должна скачать результат(xml) в папку клиента.  Если все равно недостаточно информации, тогда я просто брошу это дело. Не буду мучать Вас